# How can I write to XML via Java and display it via HTML?

Tags: java, html, xml

How can we insert a record into an XML file using Java?

How can we display one record from this XML file using HTML?

Comment: Why are y'all downvoting this? It's a programming question, right?

Comment: I don't know, because the question is not clear at all ? A minimum effort should be done on the question before asking it.

Comment: Maybe he just isn't english fluent.

Answer (score 4):

To display a record of html from xml, its called [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), which is a stylesheet language for XML,its a way to transform an xml file to display as html, you can use things like [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) to help you edit and make the transformation.

As oppose to in java; DOM parser loads the XML file into the memory and makes an object model of it. Here is a [quick Example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html) on how you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

XML to HTML : use XSLT http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0407.html
inserting another Node in a XML tree:
* use the DOM API and node.appendChild(newnode) : http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html
* if your tree is too large, use the SAX API

Answer (score 2):

```
String xml = <learn to read file and get it as String>
xml = xml.trim().replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;");
os.println("<pre id=\"content\">" + xml + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet may clarify things for you using XSLT and Java (JSTL), just complementing the good links Pierre and TStamper provided you

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<c:set var="xslDoc">
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
          <html>
          <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
              </tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
          </body>
          </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</c:set>

<c:set var="xmlDoc">
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Stop</title>
            <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>A and M</company>
            <price>8.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Red</title>
            <artist>The Communards</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>London</company>
            <price>7.80</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</c:set>

<x:transform xml="${xmlDoc}" xslt="${xslDoc}" />
```

Also, there are many technologies for making this in a servlet or a business class, I like [Apache Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)